# donut chart JS/Jquery that allows HTML tags in its label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I want a donut chart, but the problem is I can't find which JS/Jquery library out there can give me the result that I want.

I tried [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart) but apparently, it does not allow HTML tags nor at least line breaks in the label. And even if I managed to add, it seems the label is also responsible for Chart.js chart legend, so if I append too much string in the label the legend will be "broken". I just want to show more information in the label.

Not parsing the HTML tags:
[image]

```
var config1 = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data : {
            labels: [
                "Pass<br/>" +
                "Move Test: 1<br/>" +
                "Increment Test: 2<br/>" +
                "Rewrite Test: 19",
                "Fail",
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: data: [22, 4],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "#1AFF00",
                        "#FF0A0A",
                    ],
                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                        "#20FF08",
                        "#FF0000",
                    ]
                }]
        },
        options : {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'All entries that Passed vs Fail from different tests'
                },
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                }
        }
};
```

Do you guys know any other library I can use for that? Or if there's a trick I can do on Chart.js?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot write plain HTML in Chart.js labels. However, you [can use Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) instead.

Comment: @tektiv thank you, I'll give it a shot, it seems that its the only one that can do that. but its donut is not really a donut but a pie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate labels from legends by providing a label callback (in options), and you can make a tooltip label multi-line by passing an array of strings ([as per documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-item-interface)).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas");
var data = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [
            "Pass",
            "Fail",
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [22, 4],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#1AFF00",
                    "#FF0A0A",
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#20FF08",
                    "#FF0000",
                ]
            }]
    },
    options : {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'All entries that Passed vs Fail from different tests'
            },
            animation: {
                animateScale: true,
                animateRotate: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                        if(data.labels[tooltipItems.index] == 'Pass') {
                            return ['Pass','Move Test: 1','Increment Test: 2','Rewrite Test: 19'];
                        }
                        return data.labels[tooltipItems.index];
                    }
                }
            }
    }
};

var theChart = new Chart(ctx, data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="150"></canvas>
```

Comment: I did not know they call this as "tooltip" Thanks!

Comment: what about adding atual html tags like <i> for icons or <strong> ?