# How get sum of total values in stackedBar ChartJs

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to get the sum of all values of a stackedBar and include this total in tooltip.

> Note: my datasets aren't static, this is an example

```
var barChartData = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Corporation 1',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            data: [50, 40, 23, 45, 67, 78, 23]
        }, {
            label: 'Corporation 2',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            data: [50, 40, 78, 23, 23, 45, 67]
        }, {
            label: 'Corporation 3',
            backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            data: [50, 67, 78, 23, 40, 23, 55]
        }]

    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:"Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label',
                    callbacks: {
                       label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                       var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                       var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                       var total = eval(data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data.join("+"));
                       return total+"--"+ corporation +": $" + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
                  }
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Now `total` is the sum per dataset and I need the sum per stackedBar.

Example

Label A: value A

Label B: value B

Label C: value C

TOTAL: value A + value B + value C

It is possible to get that total value?

Thanks, Idalia.

Comment: Rather than a tooltip, can I have it as text in the chart itself so it can be printed out?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you should know that if you return an array instead of a single string in the `callback` of the tooltip, it will display all the strings in your array as if it were different datasets (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39291375/4864023) for more details).

So I edited a little bit your callback to the following:

```js
callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
        var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

        // Loop through all datasets to get the actual total of the index
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
            total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem.index];

        // If it is not the last dataset, you display it as you usually do
        if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex != data.datasets.length - 1) {
            return corporation + " : $" + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
        } else { // .. else, you display the dataset and the total, using an array
            return [corporation + " : $" + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'), "Total : $" + total];
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the full code [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqws6e8r/), and here is its result :

[image]

Comment: thanks so much @Tektiv , this solve my problem, Important Note: I had a problen between versions of chart.js so I changed to chart.js 2.2.1 and then works well, thanks again!

Comment: its possible to hide total legend?

Comment: @Haider Sure ! You just need to add `display: false` in the legend options, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/uqws6e8r/15/)

Comment: @tektiv i meant in the tooltip , sorry for not asking question properly

Comment: @Haider Do you mean hiding the tooltip ?

Comment: @tektiv i want to hide legend in the tooltip against total

Answer (score 25):

i modified tektiv answer to show Total only for active sets and move it to tooltips footer.

```
tooltips: {
        mode: 'label',
        callbacks: {
            afterTitle: function() {
                window.total = 0;
            },
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                window.total += valor;
                return corporation + ": " + valor.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");             
            },
            footer: function() {
                return "TOTAL: " + window.total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because the "total" entry doesn't get colored box next to it.  That better reflects the chart data since we don't graph the total as a separate data set.

Comment: Should be the preferred solution.

Comment: in another dev context I have `error TS2339: Property 'total' does not exist on type 'Window'`

Answer (score 12):

Shorter version of Gaspar's answer:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    footer: (tooltipItems, data) => {
      let total = tooltipItems.reduce((a, e) => a + parseInt(e.yLabel), 0);
      return 'Total: ' + total;
    }
  }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/g3ba60zc/2/
[image: Tooltip with total]

Comment: the best solution for my use case. thank you very much

Answer (score 11):

In the other answers you replace the last dataset, with this you don't need to

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            return _this.chart.data.labels[tooltipItems[0].index];
        },
        footer: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            let total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < tooltipItems.length; i++) {
                total += parseInt(tooltipItems[i].yLabel, 10);
            }
            return 'Total: ' + total;
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: It's typescript lang.

Comment: Best way to not store any data in `window` like other answers. Title callback is actually not needed if you don't want to modify this, by default it shows the correct label.

Comment: @CularBytes: I totally disagree... This solution works only if you have (Like the OP) nothing else than numbers in your labels (yLabel).

Comment: @FranzHuber23 of course you have some pre- and pos- checking todo, also when switching around numbers to y-axes or something. But storing in `window` makes sure you cannot re-use a function for multiple graphs, because you would obviously sum all values of all graphs.

Comment: @CularBytes You do not sum up the values if you reset `total` to `0` in every `footer` method call. But I agree with you, it's not a good practice to store the values in the `window`.

Answer (score 3):

@Haider this is what you were looking for, I had the same problem.
I have reused your code and built upon it @tektiv

I have made one small change where instead of building into the label I have made use of the afterbody. This removes the key color

afterBody code:

```
                afterBody: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                  var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex].label;
                var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem[0].datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem[0].index];
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++)
                    total += data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItem[0].index];  
                return "Total : $" + total;
            }
```

Full code here at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2b549at/1/)

[Picture demonstration of the finished tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHlDG.png)

Answer (score 2):

Using Chart.js 2.5.0

```
var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
```

returns a string value. To calculate the correct sum value you have to add a parseFloat statement:

```
    tooltips: {
            mode: 'label',
            callbacks: {
                afterTitle: function() {
                    window.total = 0;
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                    var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];

                      //THIS ONE:
                    valor=parseFloat(valor);

        window.total += valor;
                    return corporation + ": " + valor.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");             
                },
                footer: function() {
                    return "TOTAL: " + window.total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on older ChartJs version you have to handle this in a different way. I'm using Chart.js Version 2.7.2 and this is how I handled it:

```
tooltips: {
            mode: 'label',
            callbacks: {
                footer: function (data) {
                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        total += data[i].yLabel;
                    }
                    return 'Total: ' + total
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js made their own, very satisfying [solution](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/tooltip/content.html):

```
options: {
  interaction: {
    intersect: false,
    mode: 'index',
  },
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        footer: footer,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and somewhere else in your code:

```
const footer = (tooltipItems) => {
  let sum = 0;

  tooltipItems.forEach(function(tooltipItem) {
    sum += tooltipItem.parsed.y;
  });
  return 'Sum: ' + sum;
};
```

Worked just fine for me!