# How to put 2 labels and distinct tooltips from two bars

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, chart.js

I'm trying to put two more features on this chart.

At the bottom, the graph displays the 12 months of the year with two bars for each month. One is that of the current year and the other of last year.
I would like each bar is its own label to be able to display for example: April 2019 and next april 2018

And then I block on the tooltips. The still when one passes the mouse they display the information of the current year and those of the preceding year.
The problem is at the level of the total where it displays the totoal of the two years.

On my side I try to display only the total of the bar where is the mouse. In summary the total for 2019 passing the mouse on the bar of 2019 and the total of 2018 passing on that of 2018.

My fiidle :

```
jsfiddle.net/gcr8z257/3/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution to the question

You can accomplish this by changing the tooltip `mode` to `x` instead of `index`, please refer to this [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#x).

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'x'
    }
}
```

### Fixing the total value as asked

Here is a solution implemented by me based on the code presented on the question and probably from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39374290/3376838) where we can find a basic explanation who this work.

**Fist**, create an dataset array that belong to the same `stack` as the hovered tooltip, to do so:

```
var dataStack = data.datasets.filter(
    x => x.stack == data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].stack
);
```

**Then**, we can check if the `callback` is for the last dataset of this list (so the total is added only at the end)

```
if (data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex] != dataStack[dataStack.length - 1])
```

**Also**, I changed the location where the total is calculated since we only need to calculate it when the last `callback` is called.

Here is a full working example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('bar-chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [' mai', ' juin', ' juillet', ' aout', ' septembre', ' octobre', ' novembre', ' decembre', ' janvier', ' fevrier', ' mars', ' avril', ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "l'année derniere male",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(5, 90, 130)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(254, 90, 130)',
        data: [5, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 5, 0, 7, 3, 0, 8],
        stack: 1
      },
      {
        label: "l'année derniere femelle",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(120, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(254, 90, 130)',
        data: [7, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 10, 2],
        stack: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Male cette annee',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [0, 2, 0, 4, 2, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1],
        stack: 2
      },
      {
        label: 'femelle cette annee',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [0, 12, 0, 1, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 15],
        stack: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var corporation = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
          var valor = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          var dataStack = data.datasets.filter(x => x.stack == data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].stack);

          if (data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex] != dataStack[dataStack.length - 1]) {
            return corporation + " : " + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
          } else {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataStack.length; i++)
              total += dataStack[i].data[tooltipItem.index];
            return [corporation + " : " + valor.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'), "Total : " + total];
          }
        },
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMax: 50
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="bar-chart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: actually with the option on X he distinct the two bars well.
On the other hand, it always displays the total with the addition of the two bars but only on the last bar. strange.

Comment: that is because you are changing the `label` callback and only considering the last index to add the total value, to change that you have to consider de `ylabel` position where your `tooltipItem` is and then run the for loop only using the data with the same stack value.

Comment: @christophe please see the updated anwser, and let me know if it works like you expected.

Comment: The solution is exactly what I needed. I searched for the first response but I am very bad with javascript.

thank you so much

And if you know if there is a possibility to put a label by bar at the bottom of the graph I am a taker because as for my first problem I am surprised to see no graph of this type anywhere.